# V1.0.53 - Crashes on initial launch

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Ever since the last upgrade the app seems to be frequently crashing when trying to launch it (android reports the app has unexpectedly stopped) and I have to launch it a second time in order to use it. I am using a Galaxy S3 and on android 4.4.2 which is the latest version for my phone.

Comment: I'm not seeing any crash in my logs from the last 24 hours that would match the details listed here. Mind adding reproduction steps if you can, or the next time it happens hit "Report" and put in some comment, then tell me what the comment is?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I'm running into this issue. I sent a crash report (or two) via the Google feedback. I haven't completed figured it out yet. It seems to be centered around when the app is resuming from some sort of paused state.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I got another crash today and included the message "Crash Report for Kasra Rahjerdi". Hope that helps find the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.0.54 is coming out within the next few hours which resolves this issue. Thanks so much for helping do further debugging on it.

The crash was related to leaving the application while looking at a listing on a site, a specific question, or a user's profile, then coming back to the application after a period of time that caused the phone to auto-kill the background task of our application due to memory constraints. We were making some invalid assumptions in this case, which are now fixed.

Comment: Glad to know the information helped.