# Android app: switching to another app and coming back (also crashing)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

This is about the updated beta version. First of all, I wasn't sure this part warranted an entire question: the app seems to crash for no reason. It is not in reaction to anything overt that I do. I put the phone down with the app open, do something else for a second, then glance back to see the app has crashed. This happens fairly frequently. It also crashes when opening an external link.

The main bug: while I was typing an answer, I needed to do some calculations. First I changed some numbers in my answer without submitting. Then I went to my home screen, opened a calculator app, did the calculation. Afterwards I went back to the stack exchange app to put the number in and found that my changes had been undone. I think this also happens when the screen rotates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crashes are most likely the same [as this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247464/v1-0-53-crashes-on-initial-launch/247516#247516).

Were you posting a new answer or editing an answer? If you were posting a new answer, version 1.0.54 coming out in the next few hours has an additional check to make sure we save a draft when you leave the application, no matter how you leave it.

If you were editing an answer: We don't currently have edit-answer draft functionality in the app, we should, but we don't at the moment.

Comment: It was an edit. Guess it isn't a bug then.